# SQLite JDBS driver error: getarray not implemented

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

I am trying to take a ResultSet and add its contents to an array of Strings.

```
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(String.format("SELECT * FROM %s", TABLE_STUDENTS));

Array resultArrayStudent = resultSetStudent.getArray(1);
String[] studentIds = (String[])resultArrayStudent.getArray();
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4ResultSet.unused(JDBC4ResultSet.java:333)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4ResultSet.getArray(JDBC4ResultSet.java:340)
    at models.DataSource.classesTakenByEachStudent(DataSource.java:400)
    at Main.main(Main.java:81)
```

What could be causing this exception to be thrown? I am using sqlite jdbc 3.18.0.

Comment: what did you want to get an Array of Ids of Strings or an Array?

Comment: The .getArray(int) returns a SQL array. I want an Array of Strings where the strings are the student identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't get an Array directly, you have to loop throw your resultSet and get identifies, you can use :

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(String.format("....", TABLE_STUDENTS));
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();//create a List
while (resultSet.next()){//loop throw the result set
   list.add(resultSetStudent.getString("id"));//use the name of your col you want to get
}
```